# Code first table with two foreign keys one should be null if the other has value

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, check-constraints

Well, i'm trying to apply a Check Constraint to my table! So i have Country Representatives each country should have one Representative either an `Individual` or an `Organization` BUT NOT BOTH;

For example if an `Individual` is representing the country the `OrganizationId` should be `null`.

how can i apply this check constraint using Code First Data Annotations or if there is any other way.

here is my code:

```
    class CountryRepresentative
{
    [Column(Order = 0), Key, ForeignKey("Incident")]
    public Guid CountryId { get; set; }

    [Column(Order = 1), ForeignKey("Organization")]
    public int OrganizationId { get; set; }

    [Column(Order = 2), ForeignKey("Individual")]
    public int IndividualId { get; set; }

    public virtual Organization Organization { get; set; }

    public virtual Individual Individual { get; set; }

    public virtual Incident Incident { get; set; }
}
```

I hope everything is clear.
Thank you mates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use Fluent API to define the constraint manually:

```
migrationBuilder.Sql("ADD CONSTRAINT CK_ONLY_ONE_VAL CHECK 
                    ((nullif(one,'') is null or nullif(other,'') is null) 
                    and not (nullif(one,'') is null and nullif(other,'') is null) );");
```

The `nullif()` would help with checking for empty values and converts to `null`...